# Using values from one aspx.cs file to another aspx.cs file with a common class

Tags: c#, asp.net

common class file **common.cs**: This file, I have added by clicking   **add->new items-> class**

```
public class common
{
  public int v,n;
   public int da()
     {
         return n= v;
     }

}
```

Another file: It's an webpage file name is **a1.aspx.cs:**

```
common c = new common();

c.v = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text);
c.da();
Response.Redirect("ulogin.aspx");
```

the value from a text box stores in c.v variable

So, now, I want the value which was given in the textbox1.text in another webpage file named as **ulogin.aspx.cs**

I used this code:

```
common d=new common();
d.da();

Label1.Text = Convert.ToString(d.n);
```

but after running it shows the value as 0.....

Comment: You are creating two different instances, with different values. You have two solutions: create the `common` class as a static class, or save the `v` value into the `Session`.

Comment: The problem is that you have two instances of common, you should only have one.  You must find a way to move common between your pages.  One solution would be to use Session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a web application, you'll need to persist the information somewhere common (typically `Session` for per user info or `Application` for per application info) so that it can be used between different pages & user controls in your application.

I'd suggest adding a Session backed property to your page & usercontrol which accesses a common Session["variable"]. Something like the following.

(i.e. lets imagine your code was being exectued on a button click)

*a1.aspx.cs*

```
public int ValueToStore 
{
   get
   { 
       return Session["ValueToStore"] != null
           ? (int)Session["ValueToStore"]
           : 0
   }
   set
   {
       Session["ValueToStore"] = value;
   }
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    ValueToStore = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text);
    Response.Redirect("ulogin.aspx");
}
```

*ulogin.aspx.cs*

```
public int ValueToStore 
{
   get
   { 
       return Session["ValueToStore"] != null
           ? (int)Session["ValueToStore"]
           : 0
   }
   set
   {
       Session["ValueToStore"] = value;
   }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Label1.Text = ValueToStore.ToString();
}
```

As you can see, you now have some code duplication between the two pages, so the next step would be to consider implementing a basepage which as the common property, and then inherit that from a1.aspx & ulogin.aspx.

i.e.

```
public class a1 : BasePage
{
    ...
}

public class ulogin : BasePage
{
    ...
}

public class BasePage : System.Web.Page
{
    //Put ValueToStore property here.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many users visiting same page, they may set different value, and the expected result is whatever value is set by an user on **Page 1** need to be displayed in **Page 2**.

Any Web technology is stateless as they use HTTP which is stateless again.

However there are many ways to get this done, each method has their own advantages.

### **--Session--**

Please use session variable to store your value, which is a kind of variable.

Each user has different session variable to store, and its available
 Until the user logs out (i.e. till Session is available)

Storage: Server Memory

```
        public class Common
        {
          public int? Data
          {
             get
             {
                if(Session["Data"]!=null)
                {
                    return  int.Parse(Session["Data"].ToString());
                }
                return null.
             }
             set
             {
               Session["Data"]=value;
             }
          }

        }
```

### **--Query String--**

You can pass value from one page to another page using query string.

**Page 1**

```
int value=1;
Response.Redirect("Page2.aspx?data="+value.ToString())
```

**Page 2**

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request["data"]))
{
int value=int.Parse(Request["data"]);
}
```

### **--Posting--**

You can also post the value from one page to another page.

**Page 1 (html)**

```
<form action="page2.aspx" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="data" value="1"/> 
</form>
```

**Page 2**

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request["data"]))
{
 int value=int.Parse(Request["data"]);
}
```

There are even more ways... You have to select what is suitable for your scenario.

### **Read ASP.NET State management**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75x4ha6s.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If the page ulogin.aspx is designed to be always redirected from a1.aspx, then set the PreviousPageType in ulogin.aspx and get the previous page values by this.PreviousPage instance. (Cross-Page-PostBack)

Answer (score 0):

Convert member v to a property of common. Store common into a Session variable. And once you are ready to get the value, cast session variable to common and access v property from there.